# Order results by proximity (with coordinates & radius)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, geolocation, neo4j

Given a database of 4 circles, where each circle has a radius and a geolocated centre:

```
id | radius | latitude | longitude
---+--------+----------+----------
 1 |      3 |    40.71 |    100.23
 2 |     10 |    50.13 |    100.23
 3 |     12 |    39.92 |    100.23
 4 |      4 |    80.99 |    100.23
```

Note: the longitude is the same for each circle, in order to keep things simple.

Assuming that we are on the circle 2, I would like to find every circle nearby, according to the `latitude`/`longitude` coordinates and the `radius` of each circle.

For example, according to the latitude/longitude coordinates, we have this order:

1. circle 1 (because of proximity: `9.42 <- 50.13 - 40.71`)
2. circle 3 (because of proximity: `10.21 <- 50.13 - 39.92`)
3. circle 4 (because of proximity: `30.86 <- 80.99 - 50.13`)

But according to the latitude/longitude coordinates and the radius of each circle, we should have:

1. circle 3 (because of proximity: `1.79 <- 12 - 10.21`)
2. circle 1 (because of proximity: `6.42 <- 9.42 - 3`)
3. circle 4 (because of proximity: `26.86 <- 30.86 - 4`)

Is there a simple way to do so in SQL?

Comment: Do you want to do this in MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'd prefer to do it with PostgreSQL. But even just with MySQL, I would be happy ;)

Comment: How exactly are you intending to calculate the order of these? Since you consider the radius significant, you're not just concerned with the distance between the circles' centres, so please expand.

Comment: do you just mean the gc distance between the centres divided by the radius of the considered circle? (not quite sure how this calculation is useful, but it produces the order you ask for)

Comment: Actually the order would be calculated according to the distance between our circle's geolocated centre and, for each other circle which we want to list, the nearly point of the circumference (according to the radius). So we could say that: the gc distance between the cercles' circumference and the considered circle.

Comment: Can you make a math example of how you would like to calculate this?

Comment: @jester, Thanks for your comment. I just added one with proximity values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cube` and `earthdistance` extensions provided in postgresql's contrib can handle doing this, to produce at least approximate answers. Specifically, they assume the Earth is a simple sphere, which makes the math a lot easier.

With those extensions you can produce the distance between circle 2 and the others like this:

```
select circle.id,
       earth_distance(ll_to_earth(circle.latitude, circle.longitude),
                      ll_to_earth(x.latitude, x.longitude))
 from circle,
      circle x
 where x.id = 2 and circle.id <> x.id
 order by 2;
```

Correcting for the circle radius should just involve subtracting `x.radius` and `circle.radius` from the distance above, although you need to think about what units the radius is in. By default, `earth_distance` will calculate a value in metres.

Now, making the query do something other than scan the entire list of circles and calculate the distance for each one, then sort and limit them, that's much more challenging. There are a couple of approaches:

- using cube's ability to be indexed with gist, so you can create indices to search within certain boxes around any circle's centre, and hence cut down the list of circles to consider.
- precalculate the distance between each circle and all the others any time a circle is edited, using triggers to maintain this calculation in a separate table.

The second options basically starts with:

```
create table circle_distance as
select a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id,
 earth_distance(ll_to_earth(a.latitude, a.longitude),
                ll_to_earth(b.latitude, b.longitude))
 from circle a, circle b
 where a.id <> b.id;
alter table circle_distance add unique(a_id, b_id);
create index on circle_distance(a_id, earth_distance);
```

Then some rather tedious functions to delete/insert relevant rows in `circle_distance`, called by triggers on `circle`. This means you can do:

```
select b_id from earth_distance where a_id = $circle_id order by earth_distance limit $n
```

This query will be able to use that index on `(a_id,earth_distance)` to do a quick scan.

Comment: Thank you for your work, @araqnid. I'll learn PostgreSQL in order to be able to use your awesome solution. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the PostGIS Geography data types and its associated functions (eg: `ST_Distance`)rather than reinventing the wheel

Comment: Thanks for this tip. However, I'm on Heroku and the add-on is currently on private beta (https://addons.heroku.com/spacialdb). It would be great if we could do it from scratch...

Comment: I'm not sure how your radius works in relation to the latitude values. They're different measurements, so I'm not sure that you can add/subtract a radius to a latitude and make sense...

Comment: Of course, if the longitude remains the same, the answer is simple...  select  
 t1.*
from #t t1,
 (select latitude as lat from #t where id=@id) v
 where id<>@id
order by  abs(lat-
 case when latitude<lat then latitude+radius
 else latitude-radius
 end)

Answer (score 0):

I would souggest you the following:

Create 1 table for calculation of relative distances in relation to the start circle

for instance:

```
id | calc1  | calc2    
---+--------+----------
 1 |  9.42  |    1.97
 3 |  10.21 |    6.42
 4 |  30.86 |   62.86
```

Calc1 being the calculation without the radius
calc2 being the calculation with radius

then create a store procedure that will first when it is run delete the table and then fill it with the correct data and then just read the result from the destination table

[Intrudoction to store procedures](http://www.eioba.com/a/1ign/a-basic-introduction-to-postgres-stored-procedures)
[You will allso need cursor for this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)

Comment: I wonder if we could do it in two steps: first we get `calc1` thanks a subquery, and second we find `calc2` in order to order results.

Comment: ofc calc2 is just a math thing from calc1 but I like the aproch without much calculating on the result end because then you need to do it on every output and you give it to some noob programer to do it and he messes it up and then it is not the same on every output but that is something I got used to in my line of work

Answer (score 0):

In neo4j, you can look at Neo4j Spatial, tests for the different operations at https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/pipes/GeoPipesTest.java, amongst them proximity search, too, e.g. https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/pipes/GeoPipesTest.java#L150